# I just got invited to a guild. Why can't I see or talk in Guild Chat?

Tags: guild-wars-2

I just got invited to a Guild in Guild Wars 2. But after playing for a while, I noticed that Guild Chat was... unusually quiet. I know these people. They are chatterboxes. They normally *do not shut up*. So it seemed odd.

Then I tried to talk in /guild, figuring I'd kickstart some conversation. But I got an error message, informing me that "**You Are Not In A Guild**".

But that can't be right, because I can see my name on the roster! Why can't I talk in Guild Chat?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to participate in guild functions such as Chat, as well as to take advantage of various guild perks, and to contribute towards guild progression, you'll need to **Represent** that particular guild.

You can do this by pulling up the guild menu, and clicking the "**Represent**" button at the bottom of the screen. Additionally, while you can join multiple guilds, you can only represent one at a time, so you won't be able to participate in guild chat from multiple guilds simultaneously.

Comment: I find this system very interesting, I thought membership worked as in GW1. Are there any restrictions in changing representation? Can you change any time you want?

Comment: You can change any time you want. The only 'restriction' is that of access to the communal features of any one of your guilds at a time.

Comment: Don't you also have to accept the invitation into the guild (as in you don't autojoin after being invited)

Comment: @Gwen indeed you do, but the game *does* provide tooltips and prompts to get you that far. My question picks up at the point where I spent several hours confused.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz, you should probably include that information in either the question or the answer, for completionism's sake - so there's no "but this question doesn't answer my question" when we close someone else's problem as a dupe :P